# Syntax Error when setting Python Environment variable on installation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to learn python so I tried to install python 2.7, but when I set the environment, there was an error telling the syntax error that reverse to the first colon. Anyone help me, please?

```
>>> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why did you expect that line to work? It's not Python. I don't know what it is.

Comment: Seems like a novel way of making someone else write your code.

Comment: Which OS and when do you see this error - what is the context?

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Answer (score 0):

The command `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")` is not an python command instead this an operating system command to the set the `PATH` variable.

You are getting this error as you are inside the **Python interpreter** which was triggered by the command `python` you have entered in the **terminal (Windows PowerShell)**.

Please note the `>>>` at the left side of the line. It states that you are on inside **Python interpreter**

Please enter `quit()` to exit the **python interpreter** and then type the command. It should work!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to know!